# Use mixin argument to create class name in LESS

Tags: css, less, mixins, less-mixins

I'm trying to create a simple mixin in LESS for different colors I'll use for a website.

What i want is use `mixin` `argument` as a part of class name as well.

```
@green: #5FBEAA; // my color variable

.text-color(@color) {
    .text-{@color} {
        color: @color;
    }
}

.text-color(@green);
```

The output i'm getting is:

```
.text-#5FBEAA {
  color:#5FBEAA
}
```

What I want is:

```
.text-green {
  color:#5FBEAA
}
```

Comment: How do you do this in SASS or Stylus?

Comment: @blonfu i tried it in SASS/Stylus. it doesn't works that way.. my mistake. I had used that something else. got it wrong here.

Comment: ok, it seemed to me strange that you could access the variable name that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I have the solution using [Variable Names](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-names).

**Less**

```
@green: #5FBEAA;

.text-color(@colorname) {
  @color: ~"@{colorname}";
  .text-@{color}{
    color: @@color;
  }
}

.text-color(green);
```

**Output**

```
.text-green {
  color: #5FBEAA;
}
```

Comment: Nice approach. Can you explain me, why we need to assign value to `@color` variable with `~@{colorname};` even if I write like this `@colorname;`, itl works. Is there any valid reason behind it?

Comment: Can be replace `~"green"` by `green` in the call and looks better, I forgot to remove it after the tests I did. I have use `~@{colorname}` to get `green` as string. I edited the answer

Answer (score 2):

I don't think its possible. The closest solution for this will be using an additional variable.

```
@green: #5FBEAA;
 .text-color(@name,@color) {
     .text-@{name} {
         color: @color;
     }
 }
 .text-color(green,@green);
```

This will compile to

```
.text-green {
  color: #5FBEAA;
}
```